# Set scroll position from a different view in scrollview

Tags: swiftui, uiscrollview

How can I click the button from a different view and set the scroll position in a different view? the following code throws an error. I'm using `environmentalObject`. What I'm expecting is, when I click the buttons in `ButtonView` the scroll position of `ScrollView1` should set to the `3rd object or 1st object` in the `scrollview`. It works well in the same view, but does not know how to do it when it's different views.

Error: `Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'`

```
import SwiftUI

@EnvironmentObject private var environmentVariables: miscellaneousEnvironmentalVariable

struct ScrollView1: View {
var body: some View {
    
    ScrollView {
        
   
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            
            if (environmentVariables.CurrentIndexforPosts >= 0) {
                withAnimation {
                    value.scrollTo((environmentVariables.CurrentIndexforPosts), anchor: .top)}
            }
          
                            
            LazyVStack {
                Text ("TEXT 1")
                Text ("TEXT 2")
                Text ("TEXT 3")
                Text ("TEXT 4")
            }

}
        

struct ButtonView: View {
            var body: some View {
                
                Button("Go to next") {
                    environmentVariables.CurrentIndexforPosts = 3
                                }
                            }
                            .padding()
                   
                  Button("Go to previous") {
                      environmentVariables.CurrentIndexforPosts = 1
                                  }
                              }
                              .padding()
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a horrible MRE!! This is what you could mean and how it works:
One. you have to put .id()s on your ScrollView, otherwise scollTo doesn't know where to go.
Two. There have to be enough entries in the ScrollView. If all are visible, the scrollTo won't do anything.

```
class EnvironmentVariables: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentIndexforPosts: Int = 0
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject  var environmentVariables = EnvironmentVariables()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ButtonView()
            ScrollView1()
        }
        .environmentObject(environmentVariables)
    }
}


struct ScrollView1: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var environmentVariables: EnvironmentVariables
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { value in
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                        Text ("Text \(i)").id(i)
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                }
                
              .onChange(of: environmentVariables.currentIndexforPosts) { _ in
                    if environmentVariables.currentIndexforPosts >= 0 {
                        withAnimation {
                            value.scrollTo(environmentVariables.currentIndexforPosts, anchor: .top)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
            
struct ButtonView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var environmentVariables: EnvironmentVariables

    var body: some View {
        
        Button("Go to next") {
            environmentVariables.currentIndexforPosts += 10
        }
        .padding()
        
        Button("Go to previous") {
            environmentVariables.currentIndexforPosts -= 10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it throws an error for `lazyVstack` : `Instance method 'onChange(of:perform:)' requires that 'Binding<Int>' conform to 'Equatable'` what is it?. And it asked for a `wrapper` for `environmentVariables.currentIndexforPosts` so I added `$` to `$environmentVari.....`

Comment: don't add a $ ... the code run's as is.

Comment: if I didn't put $ . then `Referencing subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires wrapper 'EnvironmentObject<miscellaneousEnvironmentalVariables>.Wrapper' Insert $`

`Referencing operator function '>=' on 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'Binding<Subject>' conform to 'BinaryInteger'`

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I placed simple letter `c` instead of Capital `C` in `.CurrentIndexforPosts` now it works :) thanks a lot